# Proof or counterexample: generalized choice functions can be split into elementary choice functions

Tags: functions, set-theory

This is not an exercise but a class of functions I came across when studying partial and total orders.

Let $X$ be a (finite) set. Denote by $P$ the set of all finite subsets of $X$ without the empty set. I call $p: P \rightarrow P$ a generalized choice function on $X$ if $p(A) \subseteq A$ for any $A \in P$ and for any $A,B \in P$, $p(A) \subseteq B \subseteq A$ implies $p(A) = p(B)$. I call $p$ elementary if $|p(A)| = 1$ for any $A \in P$. Clearly, elementary choice functions behave similar to total orders in the way that they choose the "greatest" element out of a finite set of elements, and if one removes elements out of a set $A$ but does not remove $p(A)$, $p(A')$ will equal $p(A)$, i.e. the "greatest" element of a set won't change if you remove elements that are not the greatest element. Now, one can prove that if $p_1$,...,$p_n$ are elementary choice functions, then $p(A) := \cup_{i=1}^n p_i(A)$ is a generalized choice function that satisfies the two properties I mentioned above, however, many of the properties I proved for elementary choice functions do not seem to be true for generalized choice functions anymore (e.g. the property $p(A\cup B) = p(p(A)\cup p(B))$), unless I assume that every generalized choice function is a union of finitely many elementary choice functions, i.e. for every $p$ that satisfies the above two properties there exist $p_1$,...,$p_n$ with $p(A) = \cup_{i=1}^n p_i(A)$. I didn't manage to work out a proof for this assumption (I was thinking this would be a consequence of the fact that every partial order is an intersection of finitely many total orders, a proposition that is extremely easy to prove, but I didn't manage to find a similar proof for this problem). I'd be glad for help or a counterexample for a function $p$ that cannot be constructed in this way.

Comment: Could you show the proof that every partial order is an intersection of finitely many total orders?

Comment: I forgot to mention that $X$ should be a finite set, in which case $P$ is reduced to the power set of $X$ minus the empty set. In this case, you simply choose chains $C_1$,...,$C_n$ (w.r.t. your partial order $\leq$) that cover $X$. Order the elements of each $C_i$ by $C_i = \{c_{i1},...,c_{ik_i}\}$, then let $\leq_1$ be the total order induced by $c_{11} \leq c_{12} \leq ... \leq c_{1k_1} \leq c_{21} ... \leq c_{nk_n}$, let $\leq_2$ be the total order induced by $c_{21} \leq ... \leq c_{nk_n} \leq c_{11} \leq ... \leq c_{1k_1}$ and so on. Then, clearly $\leq = \cap_{i=1}^n \leq_i$.